# scipy optimize minimize always exit with REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_

Tags: python, scipy

I'm minimizing some log-likelihood using `'L-BFGS-B'` and I don't want the algorithm to stop when `REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_ <= factr*epsmch` so I set `ftol=0`:

```
min_log = scipy.optimize.minimize(fun=minus_log_lik, x0=proc_param,
                                  method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=tuple(bounds),
                                  options={'ftol':0,'gtol':1e-06}
```

However I always get a result with

> message: 'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH'

Does anyone know why? I tried to set ftol negative but this gives an error.

Comment: I used NQN python package.. no way to fix it in scipy ;)

Comment: If your real goal is to get a lower value of the gradient, you might want to switch to a root finding algorithm near the optimum. I personally had good results with scipy.optimize.root method='krylov' in this case.

Answer (score 3):

It is by design. Optimization algorithms work by making small changes in values of parameters and measuring the rate of change. (ie Think of a sled on a hill, you want to find the steepest slope).  Because you are dealing with floating point numbers you can keep making smaller and smaller changes in values.  To prevent the program from running you need some criteria for when you are done. (When you are at the bottom of the hill, it does not matter which direction you point the sled)

`ftol` sets your minimum tolerance for changes in a function call, `gtol` sets the global tolerance.   When you set it to 0 you are telling the routine to calculate a default tolerance.  When you are setting it negative, you are asking the routine to stop when
`abs(f(x)-f(x+delta)) <= ftol`  which can't happen with a negative number.

Try running with ftol:1e-6 and gtol:1e-6.  And see how long/how many iterations it take to converge on a solution.  Then try 1e-7 and see how much longer it takes.  Then notice how little change in the minimum value obtained.

Typical values for the options are options={'disp': None, 'maxls': 20, 'iprint': -1, 'gtol': 1e-05, 'eps': 1e-08, 'maxiter': 15000, 'ftol': 2.220446049250313e-09, 'maxcor': 10, 'maxfun': 15000})

See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-lbfgsb.html#optimize-minimize-lbfgsb

Comment: I understand this but the question is " how do I disable this exit condition"?  This algorithm stops either if **(1)** ' (f^k - f^{k+1})/max{|f^k|,|f^{k+1}|,1} <= factr * eps ' or if **(2)** ' max{|proj g_i | i = 1, ..., n} <= pgtol '. So i set _factr=0_ to disable **(1)** and just keep the projected gradient as exit condition. Nevertheless the algorithm converge and the message is that:  condition **(1)** is satisfy (even with factr=0)

Comment: But your question said you set ftol to 0.  You can set factr to 0, but why?  That exit condition is based on machine precision. At some point 4.999999999999999999999999 is just 5.  How many 9's do you want?

Comment: I want my projected gradient to be smaller than some threshold since I have some rescaling which force me to do that. But keeping the focus on the question, do you know why I cannot disable condition **(1)** even if _factr=0_? NB: setting _ftol_ is the same as setting _factr_ since _ftol=factr*epsmach_.

Comment: Actually  factr = ftol / np.finfo(float).eps for the method you are calling.  And  that may be the source of your problem.  I'm not sure how the casting from python floats to fortran doubles works and if 0.0 remains exactly 0 during the process.  But again ftol / factr is used used as an exit criteria based on machine precision.  It does not matter if you want a more precise gradient tolerance,  if you are hitting the percision limit then maybe there is something else wrong with your problem formulation.

Comment: If you really want to be sure you are avoiding that  exit condition, call the function directly so that you can be sure factr is 0.  From the source code:    The option `ftol` is exposed via the `scipy.optimize.minimize` interface,
    but calling `scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b` directly exposes `factr`. The
    relationship between the two is ``ftol = factr * numpy.finfo(float).eps``.
    I.e., `factr` multiplies the default machine floating-point precision to
    arrive at `ftol`.

Answer (score 2):

Although undocumented, I believe the 'normal' termination message:

> REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH

means the lack of significant change in the function value.
This is usually caused by two reasons:
The function value and gradient do not match. e.g., wrong gradient calculation.
The discontinuity exists in the range of minimization. If this is the case, switching to another method may help.